# Why is Docker able to handle SIGTERM only with & wait command?

Tags: docker

I am facing strange behavior, I have Docker image which has this entry point script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap " \
        service apache2 stop; \
        " SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
trap "exit" ERR

service apache2 start

tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

The previous script does **NOT** handles the SIGTERM as supposed, it just does nothing! (I can see that in Apache log, that it was terminated uncleanly), and Docker waits for 10 seconds and then kill it.

But when I change the last line to the following, **it works perfectly**!

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log & wait
```

The following also did **NOT** work:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log &
```

Could some one explain that behavior for me? I didn't understand why is that happening. What is that magic behind `& wait`? And is there any better way to keep Docker container running, and in the same time being able to handle the signals?

Answer (score 0):

A tad late but bash will not process the trap until the current command has exited (tail), which it will not, contrary to popular belief.  'wait' is special and is interruptible.